# Kubernetes (minikube) access to system folders from pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am working on a project in which it will be necessary to write access the host's system files.
Yes, I know it has security holes etc but it is essential. For now i try everything on minikube but ultimately is supposed to run on "normal" kubernetes as a `daemonset`.

My pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-agent
spec:
  containers:
  - image: test-agent-ubuntu:latest
    name: test-agent-ubuntu
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "100Mi"
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /sys/devices
      name: host-devices
    - mountPath: /home2
      name: host-home
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      runAsUser: 0
  volumes:
  - name: host-devices
    hostPath:
      path: /sys/devices
      type: Directory
  - name: host-home
    hostPath:
      path: /mnt/home2
      type: Directory
```

Second (/home2) mount is mounted by `minikube mount /home:/mnt/home2`.

Pod itself starts fine, description looks ok (**rw** mounts):

```
    Mounts:
      /home2 from host-home (rw)
      /sys/devices from host-devices (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-fvbhb (ro)
```

But when i try do something from pod got errors:

```
root@test-agent-c65dbc8d7-4cjvc:/opt/test-agent# echo "blabla" > /sys/devices/test
bash: /sys/devices/test: Read-only file system

root@test-agent:/home2# echo "blabla" > bbb
bash: bbb: Unknown error 526
```

Problem is in my configuration or in Minikube? Second is 100% related to minikube mounting.
How else can i edit files in `/sys/devices` from POD?

P.S. Minikube is started with driver=docker

Comment: Hello, silly thing, have you also tried to do a chmod in the pod dir itself ? are there any other pods using the same dir?

Comment: Hi, file system is "Read Only", can't do anything. This was only one pod at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Both problems arise from using Minikube. After changing to Microk8s, the same configuration works fine, i.e. I have RW access to the disk on the node.